# English words stay intact and Hebrew words are split?

Tags: css, wordpress, word-wrap

In this [wordpress site](http://www.julbaum.co.il/) I setup, in some pages, Hebrew words are split when a new line is started (as defined by the div's width) while English words are correctly kept intact.

How do I correct this issue?
I tried debugging by looking for strange or suspicious css and also looking for similar questions and answers on the web.

update: I found `word-wrap: break-word;` burried in the css. If I disable this, the whole text appears as one straight line. The weird part is that English works just fine and setting the value to normal produces unexpected results.

Comment: What happens if you add a `lang="he"` attribute to Hebrew text?

Comment: The lang is "he-IL" at the moment. and if I change it, nothing appears to happen. I am no expert but it feels like wordpress is doing the line break inside some internal mechanism perhaps?

Comment: @zehelvion If you take the HTML and put in in a static, non-WordPress, HTML file, does it still behave the same?

Comment: @MrLister
Great insight! Yes, the issue occurs and I now noticed Wordpress added an nbsp between the words instead of the spaces that were there...
Wordpress also set word-wrap to break-word.